# Best way to periodically load data (2-3 GB) into Apache Ignite cluster which is running on a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, ignite

The data needs to be loaded periodically (like once in a day), and it should be stored in SQL format so that the API can run SQL queries.
We are thinking of loading it from HDFS. Currently we are thinking of using Apache Nifi using PutIgniteCache.

I was thinking probably I can launch a remote Ignite client node and then use IgniteDataStreamer to stream the data, but I was not able to find proper documentation for that. Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: why you can't use PutIgniteCache? what problem you try to solve to find better solution?

Comment: No i just want to know whether this is the best practice and the most efficient way to do this. I was thinking of creating another service on the kubernetes cluster which will use the Java Api and use Ignite Data Streamer to load data and probably i could make it a CronJob or something.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for Nifi says that [it uses the data streamer API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-ignite-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.ignite.cache.PutIgniteCache/index.html), so unless you need more control it doesn’t seem like a bad option (with the caveat that I’d never heard of Nifi before much less used it!).

Comment: How is data loading into ignite from a HDFS usually done?

Comment: Ignite<->HDFS is not very widely used these days, but if you have to, I guess it's lazy caching via CacheStore.

Comment: The CacheStore would work. Depending on your architecture you could use something like Kafka to stream into both HDFS and Ignite at the same time. Or, as you suggest, you could write your own script to extract data from HDFS and push into Ignite. They're all valid; it depends on what you're trying to do.